# How to properly use the class? ( Target class does not exist)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller class with this default namespace and there are some uses. But I want to use also a class that I created inside the app folder in the directory `Acme/Transfomers/LessonTransformer.php`.

However when I use that like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Lesson;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;

class LessonsController extends Controller
```

Here is the constructor:

```
class LessonsController extends Controller
{
    
    protected $lessonTransformer;

    public function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer)
    {
        $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;
    }
```

The class Transformer:

```
namespace Acme\Transformers;

abstract class Transformer{
```

The class LessonTransformer:

```
namespace Acme\Transformers;


class LessonTransformer extends Transformer{
```

I get:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer] does not exist.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lessons/
```

Do you know how to properly fix this?

Comment: why did you name the file `Transform.php` if the class is `LessonTransformer`? the filename has to match the class name for psr-4 autoloading ... also why are you referencing it as `Transform` if you aliased it as `LessonTransformer`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo already updated the question. The directory is Acme/Utils/LessonTransformer.php. I added more details to the question to try to clarify better. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you using the class `Transformer`? You're showing `LessonTransformer` Including the stacktrace of the error may help.

Comment: I'm using it on the LessonsController. What do you mean by the stacktrace, all vendor errors that appear on the page?

Comment: the error message does not match the code you are showing

Comment: I updated the question with more details. Thanks!

Comment: is this `Acme` folder in the `app` folder? if that was the case the namespace would be `App\Acme\...`

Comment: Thanks but with that change it shows Undefined type 'App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to recognize a new source folder named `Acme` You need to register the  `Acme` in the `PSR-4 autloading` of **composer.json** :

```json
{
   ...

   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Acme\\": "Acme/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },

    ...
}
```

Then reload composer autoload:

$ `composer dump-autoload`

More information about PSR-4: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Thanks, but for this to work it needs to be "Acme\\": "app/Acme/" in the case of the Acme directory being inside of the app directory right?

Comment: Yes, it should work but I never tested, so I'm not 100% certain. In that case, I (personally) wouldn't use `Acme\...` namespace but `App\Acme\...` and remove `Acme` from **composer.json**. IMO, using `Acme` in `app/Acme` will bring more confusion about namespaces and folder location.